# Passing an ID to a range using the Elessar library

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, elessar

I'm using the Elessar library to create a multi-range selector: https://github.com/quarterto/Elessar

Works great so far, except for one thing... I can't seem to find any functionality to pass an ID to pre-populated ranges. This is problematic if you need to update an existing range that you're loading from a database.

Here are the options provided in the documentation:

```
new RangeBar({
  values: [], // array of value pairs; each pair is the min and max of the range it creates (Ex: [[50, 100], [150, 200]])
  readonly: false, // whether this bar is read-only
  min: 0, // value at start of bar
  max: 100, // value at end of bar
  valueFormat: function(a) {return a;}, // formats a value on the bar for output
  valueParse: function(a) {return a;}, // parses an output value for the bar
  snap: 0, // clamps range ends to multiples of this value (in bar units)
  minSize: 0, // smallest allowed range (in bar units)
  maxRanges: Infinity, // maximum number of ranges allowed on the bar
  bgMarks: {
    count: 0, // number of value labels to write in the background of the bar
    interval: Infinity, // provide instead of count to specify the space between labels
    label: id // string or function to write as the text of a label. functions are called with normalised     values.
  },
  indicator: null, // pass a function(RangeBar, Indicator, Function?) Value to calculate where to put a     current indicator, calling the function whenever you want the position to be recalculated
  allowDelete: false, // set to true to enable double-middle-click-to-delete
  deleteTimeout: 5000, // maximum time in ms between middle clicks
  vertical: false, // if true the rangebar is aligned vertically, and given the class elessar-vertical
  bounds: null, // a function that provides an upper or lower bound when a range is being dragged. call     with the range that is being moved, should return an object with an upper or lower key
  htmlLabel: false, // if true, range labels are written as html
  allowSwap: true // swap ranges when dragging past
});
```

Ideally, I think, you should be able to pass the ranges with an ID ([min, max, id]) so that you can detect which range was actually changed when you update the slider.

I think this issue off the project's GitHub may touch on it: https://github.com/quarterto/Elessar/issues/67

Is there something in the docs that I'm missing? This seems like it would be a necessary component.

Thanks,
Andrew

Comment: have you tried `.val()`? That seems to be what you're looking for, according to the [docs](https://github.com/quarterto/Elessar#val).

Comment: @vch, thanks for you reply. ``.val()`` just returns an array of the values, it doesn't indicate which value was changed. For instance, if you load a set of ranges from a database (ID/min/max), then modify the range using a slider, how do you know which of elements returned with the .val() method corresponds to the database row you'd like to update? Let me know if that question makes sense, I need coffee! :)

Comment: it looks like `.on('change'` takes a callback that includes that.

Comment: @vch the `change` event only includes the DOM element, not the Range object. This would be a useful addition though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't at all documented, but RangeBar has a method [`.addRange(range, data)`](https://github.com/quarterto/Elessar/blob/1.8.0/lib/rangebar.js#L100). The `data` parameter is stored with the range. You can create the range manually using something like

```
bar.addRange(model.getRangeValue(), {model: model})
```

and, provided your model has a method `changed` which can tell you if the value is different to what it was before (Backbone's [`changedAttributes`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-changedAttributes) for example):

```
bar.on('change', function(ev, values) {
  values.forEach(function(value, i) {
    var range = bar.ranges[i];
    if(range.data('model').changed(value)) {...}
  });
});
```

Yep, this is horrible, but it's actually how I do it in my application that uses Elessar. It makes much more sense to send the range along with `change` events (currently only the value and DOM element are passed). I'll be adding this in a future release.

Comment: Woah! Thanks for the awesome support and for building this wonderful library. You can see my use-case here: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/62928/interface-for-selecting-defining-multiple-mutually-exclusive-ranges

Comment: I'm receiving a ``Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function `` error on the changed() method after ``data('model')`` in your example. There's a property 'hasChanged: true', but it seems to be true for every range (even the ones that weren't changed). Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: My example is just pseudocode. `.changed` isn't a part of Elessar, it's a method you should implement on your data model.

Comment: @MattBrennan Should I be processing the data I pass into `.addRange` somehow? I'm passing in numbers that are between the predefined min and max, and it appears to be just multiplying them by 100 and adding %. So I've got 0, 96 on a range of 0 to 96, and it's got a range that's 9600% wide. Obviously the "easy" way to handle this would be to do my own calculation - (val - min)/(max - min) - on each value, but is that the intended way?

Comment: `addRange` expects range values, which are between `0` and `1`, as opposed to bar values, which are between `min` and `max`. You can call `rangebar.abnormalise` to transform a bar value to a range value.

Comment: @MattBrennan is there a way to change the min and max or either of the two properties of the RangeBar and redraw it? Will really appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: @praneybehl there's no direct way of doing it, but `rangebar.options.min = <minimum value>; rangebar.opitions.max = <maximum value>; rangebar.draw()` should work.